# jquery/javascript enabling and disabling select menus. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is pretty standard stuff here, and I cannot understand why it isn't working.
When the enable function is called, I receive my alert but the select fields are still disabled. Any thoughts?

```
$(window.document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectmenu1').attr('disabled','true');
    $('#selectmenu2').attr('disabled','true');
    $('#selectmenu3').attr('disabled','true');
});

function enableCoreChange(){
    alert('called');
    $('#selectmenu1').attr('disabled','false');
    $('#selectmenu2').attr('disabled','false');
    $('#selectmenu3').attr('disabled','false');
}
```

The click event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="enableCoreChange();">Click here to enable</a>
```

It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a boolean, not a string, as the second parameter of `.attr()`.

```
$(function() { // use document ready shorthand
    // combine the selectors to stay DRY
    $('#selectmenu1, #selectmenu2, #selectmenu3').attr('disabled', true);
});

function enableCoreChange() {
    $('#selectmenu1, #selectmenu2, #selectmenu3').attr('disabled', false);
    // alternately:
    $('#selectmenu1, #selectmenu2, #selectmenu3').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Note the other general style improvements as well.

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL Thank you! I'm embarrassed I missed that. Also, thanks for the example on the style improvement.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
 <a href="#" id="enable">Click here to enable</a>
```

<sub>jQuery:</sub>

```
function enableCoreChange(){
    $('#selectmenu1, #selectmenu2, #selectmenu3').prop('disabled', false); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#selectmenu1, #selectmenu2, #selectmenu3').prop('disabled', true); 

    $('#enable').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        enableCoreChange();
    });    

});
```

***[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WzFx/3/)***

<sub>Note:</sub>
Instead of `$('#selectmenu1, #selectmenu2, #selectmenu3')`: *starts with* `^` selector:

```
$('select[id^="selectmenu"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: @yannis ...that actually was a *jsFiddle* ;) Please don't up-vote for design skills ;) haha

Answer (score 1):

The attribute "disabled" does not need a value (backward compatibility) as soon as this attribute is available, it is disabled.

To activate it again use this function:

```
function enableCoreChange(){
    alert('called');
    $('#selectmenu1').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#selectmenu2').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#selectmenu3').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're specifying the string `'false'` instead of the boolean `false`.  Personally I'd use `removeAttr` for clarity

```
function enableCoreChange(){
    alert('called');
    $('#selectmenu1').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#selectmenu2').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#selectmenu3').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pznn/